# Classifying space of an algebraic torus

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I know that classifying space of a compact torus of n dimension is equal to n copies of infinite dimensional complex projective space. But how does a classifying space of an algebraic torus look like?

Comment: The topological classifying space is the same for the maximal compact subgroup, for any Lie group with finitely many compnents, which in this case is a totally real compact torus.

Comment: @BenMcKay thank you!